# How can I disable the audio notification when adjusting volume output slider in pavucontrol?

Tags: pulseaudio, desktop

I use pavucontrol to adjust the audio output volume in Manjaro Linux. I noticed today that pavucontrol emits a "pop" sound when I adjust the volume slider under the Output tab. This seems to be specific to pavucontrol, as slider controls in other applications do not emit this sound. How can I disable it in pavucontrol?

Answer (score 3):

I haven't found a configuration option for this sound specifically, but it can be silenced by setting the "system sounds" slider to 0, under the "Playback tab" (all the way to the left). This will disable all system sounds, so it may not be an ideal solution for everyone.